Nginx redirecting app to localhost/app instead of localhost:3000/app
I am running my react app on nginx server via Docker.
Without docker and nginx, my app runs fine on localhost:3000/app path.
But After adding Dockerfile and nginx, it is redirecting the path to  localhost/app, ignoring the port.
Dockerfile
FROM node:16 as build
 
WORKDIR /app
 
COPY package*.json ./
 
RUN npm install
 
COPY . .
 
RUN npm run build
 
FROM nginx:alpine
 
RUN rm -rf /etc/nginx/conf.d/*
 
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
 
COPY --from=build /app/build /usr/share/nginx/html/app
 
EXPOSE 80
 
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]

nginx.conf
server {    
    listen 80;    
    server_name localhost;    
    location /app{        
        alias /usr/share/nginx/html;        
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;    
    }
}

Below is the command, I am running for docker app
docker run -p 3000:80 app
I have tried multiple approaches for nginx.conf file and Dockerfile.
But nothing seems to work.
I am new to react and dockerfile, I feel that there is just a small piece of the puzzle which I am missing.
Any help will be appreciated.

Your nginx conf is for the docker container nginx? If it is, it's working as expected listening on Container port 80 and redirecting /app requests to wherever. Are you trying to access it from your host? if so when you run it, you've bound localhost:3000 to container port 80 so when you go localhost:3000 it'll redirect to the container and whatever default fall back you have in the server configs will take over.

how can I correct it, so it remains on localhost:3000/app?
I have tried docker run -p 3000:3000 app as well.

You'd have to introduce a reverse proxy like nginx on the host that will proxy your request localhost:3000 to your container. You could also listen on port 3000 in the nginx container and see if that works.

I would try creating a reverse proxy configuration with nginx to serve your application from port 3000, like so:
server {
listen 80;
listen [::]:80;

server_name localhost;
    
location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
    include proxy_params;
}

}
